# Can I select custom group as campaing facet?

Tags: taxonomy

I have a campaign facet called Advertising Area (just like the one found in Google Ads). Within this facet,there are 2 levels of custom groups i.e. Country and Region and the last level is City:

Campaign facet : Advertising Area
1st level group  - Australia
2nd level group    - Victoria
3rd level tag        - Melbourne

In a new campaign, I try to select "Australia" as a tag for a campaign facet but Sitecore prompts an error "Some of the fields in this item contain fatal errors".

Does it mean I can't use custom group as tag in campaign facet?

Thank you,

Roman

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: We are currently using version 9.01

Comment: I do not know this error, but do have the same problem in v8.1 I thought it was due to creating a facet 2 prior to campaign facet 1, but tried changing it and still get the message.